# directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR is not firing for DirectUpload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using rails activestorage on a ecs class

```
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";

function createDirectUpload(file, source, controller) {
  return new DirectUpload(file, source.url, source.token, source.attachmentName, controller);
}
```

In my constructor I create a new DirectUpload

```
constructor(source, file) {
  this.directUpload = createDirectUpload(file, source, this);
  this.source = source;
  this.file = file;
}

start() {
  this.source.fileUploader = this;
  this.hiddenInput = this.createHiddenInput();
  this.directUpload.create((error, attributes) => {
    if (error) {
      this.hiddenInput?.parentNode?.removeChild(this.hiddenInput);
      this.emitDropzoneError(error);
    } else {
      this.hiddenInput.value = attributes.signed_id;
      this.emitDropzoneSuccess();
    }
  });
}

directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(xhr) {
  this.bindProgressEvent(xhr);
  this.emitDropzoneUploading();
}
```

When I call `start` it works as expected, but the callback `directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR` is not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track the progress of the file upload, you can pass a third parameter to the DirectUpload constructor `new DirectUpload(file, source.url, this)`

And you pass it as a fifth parameter `return new DirectUpload(file, source.url, source.token, source.attachmentName, controller);`

You initialiser should look like this:

```js
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";

function createDirectUpload(file, source, controller) {
  return new DirectUpload(file, source.url, controller);
}
```